# Impossible to achieve a Zoom in/out with webcam using actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, webcam, zooming

I am guessing this is not possible based on the fact that my Google search did not yield anything!

So asking the stackoverflow talent, is it possible for me to get webcams to zoom in and out providing the webcam has zoom capability? I am guessing no?

This is for an image capture project that I am doing.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use the webcam's own zoom capability. 
You could implement a "digital zoom" though, depending on the resolutions supported by the camera it might look either totally crappy or half-decent.

Comment: Yeh, was thinking about the digital zoom, i guess i have to go for the less useful option. Thanks :)